# Temporary table doesn't exist error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

Couldn't call stored procedure with temporary table:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `summary_daily_reports`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE  `summary_daily_reports`()
BEGIN

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `both_daily_repots`;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE both_daily_repots(
       `date`        VARCHAR(10),
       balance         DOUBLE,
       balance_ua         DOUBLE
       ) DEFAULT CHAR SET utf8;



INSERT INTO both_daily_reports VALUES ('2012-01-01',0,0);

SELECT * FROM both_daily_repots;

END $$
```

Then i call procedure and get error "Table 'report_cfd.both_daily_reports' doesn't exist";

Comment: You might wish to fix the typo in the DROP and CREATE table names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a few places you spell the table name as `both_daily_repots` instead of `both_daily_reports`. This is what's causing the error.

What happens is that:

- `DROP TABLE`, `CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT` operate on `repots` (without the `r`);
- `INSERT` tries to insert into `reports` (with the `r`) and fails.

Comment: hi @NPE, i have a question about temporary table here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918066/creating-mysql-temporary-table-then-assign-crud-from-it can u give me a try? thanks