# Creating MySQL Temporary Table then Assign CRUD From It

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

i have created a stored procedure which have logic like this:

1. getting the data result from 2 tables then create temporary table based on it (the data range is selected using two parameter start date and end date).
2. select few columns from the temporary table then assign to another table (eg. X)
3. update the table (X).

this is my stored procedure syntax:

```
  DELIMITER $$

  USE `sre`$$

  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_checkPotentialProductf`$$

  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_checkPotentialProductf`(IN sdate DATE, IN edate DATE)
BEGIN 
DECLARE sumtotal INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE first_margin DOUBLE;
DECLARE count_rows INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE startnum INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE start_mrg DOUBLE;
DECLARE adder DOUBLE;

/* assign table temporary and select the values */

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vShowTopSellingQuantitys AS
 SELECT
  `mt_pesanan`.`ms_langganan_idms_langganan`  AS `idms_langganan`,
  `mt_pesanan`.`ms_langganan_idms_kodebarang` AS `idms_kodebarang`,
  `md`.`nama`                         AS `nama`,
  `mt_pesanan`.`quantity`                     AS `quantity`,
  `mt_pesanan`.`harga`                        AS `harga`,
  `mt_pesanan`.`jumlah`                       AS `jumlah`,
  `mt_pesanan`.`discount`                     AS `discount`,
  `mt_pesanan`.`tgl_pesan`                    AS `tgl_pesan`,
  SUM(`mt_pesanan`.`quantity` )   AS `sum_product`
 FROM `mt_pesanan`  JOIN `ms_barang` `md`
 WHERE ((`mt_pesanan`.`tgl_pesan` <= edate) AND (`mt_pesanan`.`tgl_pesan` >= sdate)) 
       AND (md.`idms_kodebarang` = `mt_pesanan`.`ms_langganan_idms_kodebarang`)
     GROUP BY `mt_pesanan`.`ms_langganan_idms_kodebarang`
     ORDER BY SUM(`mt_pesanan`.`quantity` ) DESC;
/* end assign table temporary */

/* assign values to variables */
SELECT SUM(sum_product) INTO sumtotal FROM `vShowTopSellingQuantitys`;
SELECT COUNT(sum_product) INTO count_rows FROM `vShowTopSellingQuantitys`;
SELECT (sum_product/sumtotal)*100 INTO first_margin FROM `vShowTopSellingQuantitys` LIMIT 1; 

/* truncate database tmp*/ 
TRUNCATE tmp_produkpotensial;

/*creating algorithm to analyze the percentage quantity/total */
SET startnum = 1;

/*show result with percentage*/
SELECT `idms_kodebarang`, `nama`, sum_product , ((sum_product/sumtotal)*100) AS 'pecentage_margin' FROM `vShowTopSellingQuantitys`;

/*result execution from temporary table to analyze potential product */
INSERT INTO tmp_produkpotensial(idms_kodebarang,nama,percentage_margin)
SELECT `idms_kodebarang`, `nama`, ((sum_product/sumtotal)*100) AS 'percentage_margin' FROM `vShowTopSellingQuantitys`;

/* update the sum total of percentage */    
WHILE(count_rows >= startnum) DO
IF(startnum = 1) THEN
  SET start_mrg = 0;
  UPDATE tmp_produkpotensial SET tmp_produkpotensial.sum_margin = (percentage_margin + start_mrg) WHERE id_barang = startnum;
ELSE
  SELECT sum_margin INTO start_mrg FROM tmp_produkpotensial WHERE id_barang = (startnum - 1);
  UPDATE tmp_produkpotensial SET tmp_produkpotensial.sum_margin = (percentage_margin + start_mrg) WHERE id_barang = startnum;
END IF;

/* Assign Update to Update Sum Margin Column */
SET startnum = startnum + 1;
END WHILE;


 END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

The stored procedure is successfully compiled, but when i call the stored procedure it always returns 0 rows.

syntax to call the stored procedure:

```
  CALL `sp_checkPotentialProductf`('2012-12-31','2012-01-01');
```

My Questions:

1. can temporary table is used again to create further CRUD statement?
2. is there any ideas where the fails goes on?

thanks

Comment: is there anyone willing to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, i have discovered a mistake. The method to call the stored procedure is

```
CALL `sp_checkPotentialProductf`(2012-12-31,2012-01-01);
```

without the quotes.